# Update Links prompt in Excel still shows

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem with this code. Excel still shows the update links prompt even though i already included these codes:

```
     Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name).UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksNever
     AppExcel.AskToUpdateLinks = False
```

Am i doing it wrong?

Here is the snippet of my code:

```
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs dirName & "\" & folderName & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name).UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksNever
    AppExcel.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name).Close False
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you puting the code in workbook events like `Workbook_Open` or `Workbook_Close`?

Comment: Nope. I'm putting it in a Sub which is called in a button_click event.

Comment: This Sub opens other workbook and save it as different filename. @MarkFitzgerald

Comment: Hey @MarkFitzgerald, thanks for the response! :) I already figured it out. I just needed to put this `UpdateLinks:=True` on my `Workbooks.Open` code

Comment: Congrats! Looks like a serendipitous solution has emerged. Glad to inspire you to find it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already got it right! :) But, thanks for the help. I just needed to put `UpdateLinks:=True`

```
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=fileName, UpdateLinks:=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
Sub Auto_Open()
    UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksNever
    AskToUpdateLinks = False
End Sub
```

Comment: I already figured it out. but, thanks for the response though :)